# Windows Phone 8.1 composite.Size threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I am trying to store an object in the localsettings of my app. For eg: trying to store user_id and name so that it can be retrieved from other pages after login with passing it everytime from one page to another. After reading tutorials from msdn as well as other sites I did this

```
var localsettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
composite["User_Id"] = 1;
composite["User_Name"] = "XYZ";
localsettings.Values["User_Session"] = composite;
```

But the values are never stored in composite variable. On debugging it shows composite.Size threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on C#, but [ApplicationDataCompositeValue.Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.size) available only for C++ and JavaScript

Comment: buddy winrt libraries are written in c++ so it is possible that the exception thrown is in regard to c++

Comment: Take a look at [ApplicationDataCompositeValue class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx) near properties written languages [C#, VB] or [C++, JavaScript] for example